# Absolutely forcing a catch of an Error in Haskell

Tags: exception, haskell

I am using the hs-excelx library that itself uses zip-archive.  zip-archive is reaching a condition in which it calls `fail`, which in that particular context, evaluates to a call to `error`.  This is a call to `error` in pure code.

I'm trying to detect whether a particular file is actually an Excel file.  It's actually necessary for me to detect this without crashing, so I have written a function called isExcel to do the detection:

```
import qualified Data.Excelx as E

isExcel :: BS.ByteString -> Bool
isExcel = maybe False (\_ -> True) . E.toExcelx
```

Now, the catch is that this is a mere formality.  If you call E.toExcelx on a bytestring that is not a zip archive, zip-archive will simply `error` out.

But, I know that I'm calling `isExcel` in IO code, so I wrote an IO function to try to catch the error like this:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Control.Exception

sd :: BS.ByteString -> IO Bool
sd bs = handle handler $ do
        ie <- return $ Excel.isExcel bs
        return (ie `seq` ie)
    where
    handler :: SomeException -> IO Bool
    handler e = return False

> sd BS.empty
*** Exception: too few bytes. Failed reading at byte position 4
```

What is going on?  According to what I've read at http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Error_vs._Exception and other places, I should be catching the exception and converting it to something useful.  `ie` in my code might be a thunk to a Bool, but how can running `seq` on `ie` possibly leave anything unevaluated?  How can I possibly catch an exception like this when I can't even figure out how to force the evaluation of a value?  I don't have time to go in and hack proper error handling into zip-archive.

Comment: Have you tried using a bang pattern to bind `ie` or the strict `$!`?  I believe there are cases where `seq` does not properly evaluate a value fully to NF, but I don't know enough about it to properly comment on when those cases are.

Comment: I've tried the bang pattern in a few places and have not yet found a case in which it changed anything in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are few things going wrong here.  First, to force the evaluation of a value in IO, use `Control.Exception.evaluate`.  This function has the type `evaluate :: a -> IO a`, and it's basically a hook to tell the compiler to force an evaluation.  Its sole reason for existence is to enable exception handling.

Next, you need some machinery to actually catch the exception.  You're currently using `handle`, but `Control.Exception.try`, which has the type `try :: Exception e => IO a -> IO (Either e a)`, is probably a bit simpler to use here.  This type is slightly odd, but it means that, for some exception type you specify, it `try` will either return the value or an exception.  If evaluation threw an exception that isn't the type you specified (and can't be coerced to it), `try` will re-throw the exception.

Calls to `error` produce an exception of the type `ErrorCall`, so to handle the exception you could use

```
sd :: BS.ByteString -> IO Bool
sd bs = do
        ie <- try $ evaluate $ Excel.isExcel bs
        either (const False) (id) (ie :: Either ErrorCall Bool)
```

of course you know that `isExcel` will only return `True`.  You could use `toExcel` directly, and modify the `either` line to accommodate that.

As to the source of your problem,

```
a `seq` a
```

is *exactly equivalent* to `a`.  It means, "at the time you evaluate (the second) `a`, evaluate (the first) `a` too".  In other words, it's still too lazy.  That's why you need `evaluate`.

Comment: I searched documentation for *months*.  I even read the strict-io library.  Never before have I found evaluate nor seen a reference to it.  The need to be *EXTREMELY* strict in IO evaluation, is common enough that why does this not get a much higher prominence in documentation?

Comment: I have no idea why it's not mentioned more prominently, although I think it's because these days best practice recommends avoiding exceptions in pure code.  Also, it is technically possible to get the strictness you want with `seq`, just not the way you were using it.